# Failed to install or upgrade Microsoft Store package. Error code: 0x80073d05

Tags: windows, windows-10, winget

I am using Winget to install Quick Share because I can't install any app through the MS Store.
but keep getting the same error on Winget and MS Store.

`Failed to install or upgrade Microsoft Store package. Error code: 0x80073d05`

I tried resetting MS Store, reinstalling MS Store, chkdsk and DISM.exe But they wouldn't fix the error.

I tried doing `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
and sfc /scannow as listed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-0x80073d05-installing-windows-store/c1d82b91-35f4-4f91-bd95-277723129680) but they also didn't work.

My old user account got corrupted because I stopped all services and couldn't login back so I had to make new one with replacing cmd with utilman with bootable drive and enable all services by hand  I think that may be the reason for getting this error message.

[image: MS Store]

[image: Winget]

---

I don't think this is related to this issue but,
I keep getting this notification every time I turn on my laptop but in Windows Security, the firewall is shown as active. And the Windows firewall troubleshooter didn't detect any problems.

[image: notification]

[image: Windows Security]

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-0x80073d05-installing-windows-store/c1d82b91-35f4-4f91-bd95-277723129680

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Comment: Please do, and [edit] the question to update it accordingly.

Comment: It didn't  work, and Sync Licenses option has been removed on Windows 10.

Comment: At some point, reinstalling windows may be a good idea.

Comment: @Gantendo I don't want to reinstall windows.

Comment: @ZoomMan2 Well, it is often less of a waste of time than trying to diagnose and fix stuff like this.

Comment: You could try a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and it keeps all apps and settings.

Comment: @harrymc I don't want to remove any app
```In Windows 10, this feature no longer preserves user-acquired Windows apps.```

Comment: I'm not talking about "Refresh your PC" or "Reset your PC" - these are just the fallback options. Bypass these two and continue on reading the article.

Comment: @harrymc thank you, In-Place-upgrade worked perfectly.
post it as answer :)

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to perform
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This operation  is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and
it keeps all apps and settings.

It seems as if some component(s) in Windows were corrupted, or that
Windows Update was partially unsuccessful. The Repair Install has
set all Windows components to a known and coherent state, so
the corruption was repaired.